# HorizontalScrollView cannot work with android:weightSum?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

My layout as follows, If I remove the `android:weightSum="3"` then everything is ok, but if I put `android:weightSum="3"` in LinearLayout(so each TextView has 1/3 width of the screen), the HorizontalScrollView seems cannot be scrolled, anyone knows why? thx

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/oneMonth"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_title"
                    android:text="one"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/threeMonth"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_title"
                    android:text="two"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/halfYear"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_title"
                    android:text="three"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/oneYear"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_title"
                    android:text="four"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/thisYear"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_title"
                    android:text="five"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/beginNow"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_title"
                    android:text="six"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: You gave weigthsum 3 but your child is exceeding the limit 3

Comment: change weightsum 3 to 6

Comment: Why are you using weigthsum=3 when you are dividing it to 6 parts ? Either give android:layout_weight=".5 or give weigthsum=6 to your Linear Layout

Comment: @Khizar Hayat, @Rakshit Nawani,  obviously, you guys misunderstand the question, If I do want each textView to be 1/3 of the screen width, so surely I should make weigthsum=3,  My question is why the horizontalscrollview cannot be scrolled when `android:weightSum="3"` is used

Answer (score 0):

I did it by this way:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels/YourChildWeight, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
parentView.addView(childView, params);
```

You need to give **ChildWeight**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But why if `android:weightSum="3"`  setted, the Horizontalscrollview cannot be scrolled?

Comment: @TigerWang, Need to fix with display width because Horizontal scrollview does not have X limit.

Answer (score 0):

Tiger Wang,

I am also looking for solution to this.

I want to use HorizontalScrollView and have 10 buttons of equal size, but show 5 equal size buttons at a time without using wrap_content for all buttons.

For buttons, I want to specify layout_weight, weightSum and layout_width="0dp".

Let me know if you find solution to this.

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: sorry, I have no solution either.